# \newenvironment{myenvironment} with tcolorbox that takes an argument

Tags: tcolorbox

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{myoption/.style={colback=blue!20}}
\newcommand{\bubble}[1]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[myoption]
        #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \bubble{\lipsum[1][1-2]}
    
\end{document}
```

I have this code from here.

I would like to define my own environment and use the macro inside it.

```
\begin{document}
    
\begin{myenvironment}
    
\bubble{\lipsum[1-2]}

\end{myenvironment}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends of what you want to put inside this environment but here is a first example.

```
%%%%%%% preamble %%%%%%%%
\usepackage{enumerate,enumitem} %for lists
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{specifications}[1][]{%
enhanced, width=0.9\textwidth ,center,
colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!85!black,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm},title=\textbf{Specifications},
boxed title style={colframe=blue!85!black,colback=blue!85!black},#1}
%%%%%%% document %%%%%%%%
\begin{specifications}
This project deals with synthesing and characterizing lanthanide-based MOFs to investigate if these materials can be used as platforms for detecting selected VOCs. The tasks to be completed are listed below. 
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbullet]
\item Read literature on MOFs 
\item Plan the experimental work
\item Carry out the syntheses of different lanthanide-based MOF
\item Characterize synthesized MOF 
\item Investigate the porosity, stability, and luminescent properties of the synthesized MOFs
\end{enumerate}
\end{specifications}
```

Here is the result.
[image]

For some reason, if caption for your environment is needed here is one posibility.
The next example shows a way to include code which can be listed in a "List of codes".

```
%%%%%%%%%% preamble %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} %for box
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{newfloat} %create floating environment (such as Figure, Table, ...)
\usepackage{capt-of} %caption for non-floating environement / breakable envir.
%% list of codes (for matlab codes) %listofcodes
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Code},fileext={loc},listname={List of Codes}]{code}
\usepackage{listings} %IT in latex
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier} %upgrade of listings specific to matlab code
%%%%%%%%%% document %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\captionof{code}{Matlab code for TGA computations}\label{code:TGA_calculations} % place the caption
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,arc=0mm,left=1pt, right=1pt, boxrule=1mm,colback=BrickRed!5!white,colframe=BrickRed!85!black] 
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Matlab, numbers=left, style=Matlab-editor]
%code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Here is the result.
[image: code environment]

The `breakable` option allows the environment to be displayed on several pages.
I think the second one can be optimized in one `\newenvironment` like the first one but it just was to give examples.

If you want to try other things, you can try reading the [manual of `tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en).
The section "Technical Overview and Customization" can be helpful for your problem.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much. Thank you !!!!!
I really appreciate this.

Comment: That is really cool. Producing tcolorbox Environments and Commands on page 15 and 16 in the manual of tcolorbox :D 
@Tony, thank you so much !!!!!

Comment: I'm happy that it helped you . @Kerry Good luck in  your writing .