# 3 or 4 arguments for `\newtcolorbox`

Tags: tcolorbox

This question follows https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688116/298558 .

Here, I asked a question about \newtcolorbox taking agruments. On page 15 on the manual there is an example that takes 2 arguments:

```
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=red!85!black,enhanced, attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
title={#2},#1}
```

```
\begin{mybox}[colback=yellow]{Hello there}
This is my own box with a mandatory title
and options.
\end{mybox}
```

I would like to pass 3 or 4 arguments to \newtcolorbox so that it takes the following form:

```
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[4][]{colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=red!85!black,enhanced, attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
title={#2}, height = #3, halign = #4, #1}
```

This works:

```
\begin{mybox}[colback=yellow]{Hello there}{0.3\textheight}{flush center}    This is my own box with a mandatory title   and options. \end{mybox}
```

This doesn't work:

```
\begin{mybox}[colback=yellow, halign = flush left]{Hello there}{0.3\textheight}
```

I would be pleased, if someone could give me ideas.

Comment: Write `[4]` instead of `[3]`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't function :)

Comment: if you show no example or error message it is hard to help

Comment: ```\newtcolorbox{mybox}[4][]{colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
 colbacktitle=red!85!black,enhanced, attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
 title={#2}, height = {#3}, halign = {#4}, #1}```

Then, I use ```\begin{mybox}[colback=yellow]{Hello there}{0.3\textheight}
 This is my own box with a mandatory title
 and options.
\end{mybox}```

I get the error: "Package pgfkeys Error: Choice 'T' unknown in choice key '/tcb/halign'. I am going to ignore this key. T"

Comment: i would like to overwrite predefined parameters with:

``\begin{mybox}[colback=yellow, halign = flush left]{Hello there}{0.3\textheight}
 This is my own box with a mandatory title
 and options.
\end{mybox}```

Comment: edit the question putting code in comments does not work well, but  `[4][]{` defines a command with one optional and three mandatory arguments so `#4`  is `T` in your example and the body starts `his is my own`

Comment: HI David, thanks. So this works: ```\begin{mybox}[colback=yellow]{Hello there}{0.3\textheight}{flush center}
 This is my own box with a mandatory title
 and options.
\end{mybox}```

Comment: I would like to change it into something like: ```\begin{mybox}[colback=yellow, halign = flush left]{Hello there}{0.3\textheight} ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provided no example in the question but in comments you show

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[4][]{%
    colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colbacktitle=red!85!black,enhanced, attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
    title={#2}, height = {#3}, halign = {#4}, #1}
\begin{document}
 
\begin{mybox}[colback=yellow]{Hello there}{0.3\textheight}
    This is my own box with a mandatory title
    and options.
\end{mybox} 
\end{document}
```

which produces

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: Choice 'T' unknown in choice key '/tcb/halign'. I am g
oing to ignore this key.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10    T
        his is my own box with a mandatory title
?
```

Note  the linebreak after `T` showing this has been read. It is the 4th argument of your command, so produce `halign={T}` and the error shown.

You could use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[4][]{%
    colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colbacktitle=red!85!black,enhanced, attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
    title={#2}, height = {#3}, halign = {#4}, #1}
\begin{document}
 
\begin{mybox}[colback=yellow]{Hello there}{0.3\textheight}{left}
    This is my own box with a mandatory title
    and options.
\end{mybox} 
\end{document}
```

But mixing keyval and positional arguments is an anti-pattern, I would use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colbacktitle=red!85!black,enhanced, attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
    title={#2}, #1}
\begin{document}
 
\begin{mybox}[colback=yellow, height = 0.3\textheight, halign =left]{Hello there}
    This is my own box with a mandatory title
    and options.
\end{mybox} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both suggestions work well. Thank you very much !!!!